# decreasing font size in a text box dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to dynamically control the font size in a text area / text box so it decreases while the user types? (ie the character *i+1* is smaller than character *i*)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in a text area or a text box.  The font-size specified for those controls will affect all text in them.  You could, however, achieve the effect by using a regular `<div>` and making its content editable, as is done in WYSIWYG editors.

[Here's](http://perplexed.co.uk/993_contenteditable_cross_browser_wysiwyg.htm) a simple example.